# Merging Objects into a Single Object

Tags: unreal-engine

I made a vehicle model on Blender to use in an Unreal Engine 4 project. The model i created has different objects such as trunk, top or doors of the vehicle and also has some modifiers on especially on the rims and tires(curves and arrays).

The problem i had occurs when i try to import the mesh into the unreal engine, the documentation and the tutorials i have found all suggest that importing the vehicle as a single car mesh.

I tried to find how to merge the objects of the blender into a single one but all i could find the CTRL+J (which does not inherits the modifiers) and the boolean method which crashes blender. How can i merge them into a single mesh without any loss in properties (modifiers)?

As this is the blender stackexchange i am not asking the unreal engine solution that i can think of such as modular meshes in vehicles but if there is anyone with such experience i would be more than happy to hear.

*As i am really new to both of the softwares (1 week) i couldnt find neither any walk around solution nor the way how to search for the problem.*

Comment: yes if you join the objects it will only keep the modifier of the last selected (active) object. But you can apply the modifiers before joining.

Comment: That's what i wanna go around of, i have one object with curve modifier and one without any. If i select the one with the curve as active and join them, automatically the one without the curve modifier is applied the curve modifier and the model is going insane, and vice versa if the one without the curve is active then the the one that should have got the curve modifier is not applied the curve thus flattens the mesh.